# iTunes is splitting one podcast into multiple podcasts. How do I fix it?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, podcasts.app

[image]
I did not have this problem, until today. A new episode of Cult of Mac came out (#39). It was put into a different podcast folder, even though the episodes before it, have the same metadata. I tried many things; Editing the sorting fields, deleting and re-adding, downloading the #39 again, but none of the methods worked.

How do I non-destructively combine the three folders into one?
(On the disk, the podcasts are in the same folder)

If it matters, I use the Podcasts app on my iPod touch.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the podcast moved to a different URL. A program like MP3Tag can show and edit extended properties (looks something like PodcastURL). Check the splinter episode and check its URL. Check an older episode. If it has changed, select all older episodes and edit the field. Click OK. Go to iTunes and Get Info for all of those episodes. When it reads the new URL, it should stick them all back together.

Redownloading the older episodes, if available, will accomplish the same thing. (They'll be downloaded from the new URL. But the tag edit is quicker and easier.

Answer (score 0):

Itunes did this to me every time the `podcasturl` changed.  Here's how to fix it:

1. Copy all of the episodes from iTunes to a temporary processing folder.
2. Delete the files and their podcast listings from iTunes.
3. Inspect the old iTunes folder(s) -- EG: `...\iTunes Media\Podcasts\EconTalk` -- for any remaining episode files.  Frequently, iTunes fails to delete these.  If any are present, delete them to avoid clutter and save space.
4. Using a tag tool like [MP3TAG](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/), inspect the `podcasturl` tag of each file.
5. Find the most recent value of `podcasturl`, that's not blank.
   EG: `http://files.libertyfund.org/econtalk/EconTalk.xml`
6. Set all of the files to have that same value.
7. At this time, I strongly recommend that you ensure that either the `title`, or the `releasetime`, or the `track` tags are set and ordered by episode, or to taste.
8. Add the retagged files back to iTunes. I typically do this by moving them to the `Automatically Add to iTunes` folder.
9. Done!  The episodes will reappear in iTunes, under a single listing, and be sortable by whatever method you established in step 7.